# error C2447: '{' : missing function header -- Can't resolve this error, what's wrong?

Tags: c, function, validation, input, header

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bcio2.h"
int error, x;
char totalimpulse[80], averageimpulse[80];
void validate_number();

int main(void)
{
    clrscr();
    do{
        printf("\nTotal Impulse delivered: ");
        gets(totalimpulse);
        validate_number();
    } while (error != 0);
    printf("You entry %d was valid\n", x);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

{   //error C2447
    clrscr();
    do{
        printf("\nAverage Impulse delivered: ");
        gets(averageimpulse);
        validate_number();
    } while (error != 0);
    printf("You entry %d was valid\n", x);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The brackets seen to match and there doesn't seem to be any unnecessary semicolons. I'm assuming this is the correct way to display input/validation. It works fine when run with just the *do…while();* loop for *totalimpulse* but when I copy/paste the exact same between another pair of { } I get just that C2447 error.

Comment: that block is outside of main.

Comment: BTW: the header file conio.h  is not portable (and generally does not exist outside of windows OS)  suggest remove the related #include and use the standard system functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that starts where the error is is not inside `main`, or any other function for that matter.  If you remove the braces on the error line and the one preceding it, then your second loop will also beside of `main`.  If you want that section to be a different function, you have to include the header for that function.  What you put at the top for `validate_number` is just a promise that you *will* define that function somewhere (although if you mean for that section at the bottom to be `validate_number`, I'm pretty sure you don't want it to be recursive).

Answer (score 1):

Right now you just have a block of code, outside any function.

I'm assuming from the rest of your code, that this block of code is supposed to be the definition of `void validate_number();`, like this:

```
void validate_number()
{
    clrscr();
    do{
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Do note that a `void` function cannot return a value, so your `return 0` should be removed.